# rails app with 2 databases - 1 used to read data the other used to write data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, connection

I needed to import some legacy data from a sqlite3 db into my rails app with postgresql db. So I created a model "businesses" with all the column types of the legacy sqlite3 db. I changed the database.yml file, etc etc......
In the model business.rb I added this line:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base

establish_connection "citylistings_development"
end
```

This allowed me to connect to the sqlite3 db and I created a index.html.erb file where I could see the contents in my browser.

In the controller my code was this:

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
def get_all
  @businesses = Business.all
end

def create_db_entries
 self.get_all
end

def index
respond_to do |format|
  format.html #index.html.erb

end
end
end
```

Now I noticed that when I created the model "business.rb It created the table in my postgresql db.

However, clearly its reading the data from my sqlite3 db because its connecting to that db.

My question is this,

how do I write the data that its outputing to the index.html.erb file into the pg db? Is this even possible?

Can a Model instance connect to 2 databases at once and read from 1 and write to another ?

I know one way to solve this would be to create another model "tempbiz" which will write entries into the pg db while the "business" model reads from the sqlite3 db. What I would like to know if the "business" model can do both tasks?

Thanks

---

EDIT
Here is my database.yml as per the comment below (Ive excluded all the commented out stuff)

```
#===============================================================================
development:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: XXX_development
 pool: 5
 username: XXX
 password: XXXX
#===============================================================================
citylistings_development:
 adapter: sqlite3
 database: db/citylistings.sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
```

Comment: could be handy somehow, at least good to know: https://github.com/tchandy/octopus

Comment: post your database.yml,  it's weird that the business table got created in pg db????   I don't think you can split a model like you want,  you'll have to just create a loop,  reading from legacy and writing to pg db.

Comment: Added the database.yml- please see edited section above Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a presentation on this topic and you need to checkout the secondbase gem. To quote its documentation "SecondBase adds a second database to your application. While Rails enables you to establish connections to as many external databases as you like, Rails can only manage a single database with it’s migration and testing tasks."

```
https://github.com/karledurante/secondbase
```

It was created for the exact reason you need it. They had a legacy database that they needed to import.

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

This will be native in Rails 6.

```
class AnimalsBase < ApplicationRecord
  connects_to database: { writing: :animals, reading: :animals_replica }
end
```

Here's the [PR that introduced it](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34052).